# How to snap to vertex on an unstraight/uneven axis?

Tags: snapping

I'm trying to mode the selected edge so that it's aligned with the vertex below. As you can see all the similar edges are uneven, made with the knife tool.

If I hold the red arrow on the gizmo I can snap to the vertex but it would ruin my angled plane at the top of the bridge.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you so much!

[image: aligning the edges to the half cylinder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep using the knife tool then align the edge after, using "edge slide".

Edge slide is a way to grab along edges and is obtained by typing <kbd>G</kbd> twice.

So here:

- make the cut
- select the edge and use <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (double keys does not appears on the cast in the gif below) to align to the edge on the right.
- then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> again to place it where you want, but this time the edge is parallel to the one on the right

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Although I know the GG function and even when i use it, it doesn't help me. On your example you're snapping to straight edges (edges that align with one of the 3 axes, not sure what the right term is) - in which case GG works well, but I want to snap to an edge but keep my slope/decline.